# RegEx - First Two Octet Match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to learn RegEx using ImmersiveLabs/LinkedInLearning and other web-based resources and things are going well.
There's a small question to which I'm not sure how to even Google for an answer.
Scenario, Azure ATP Query wherein I wanted to match Private Addressing Scheme

```
| where From_IP matches regex @'(^127\.)|(^10\.)|(^172\.1[6-9]\.)|(^172\.2[0-9]\.)|(^172\.3[0-1]\.)|(^192\.168\.)'
```

It works well! Matches what I want it to. The question is - why?!
For e.g. (~172.2[0-9].) shouldn't this only match on the first two octets of the string **172.20**.1.9 ? Why is then the entire IP matched successfully?
Seems weird for me to question something that is working. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: There is no $ in your regex so your regex does not asserts position at the end of a line, so it basically doesn't care what comes after 172.20. , see for more info: https://regex101.com/r/TgjdVz/1

Comment: What makes you think the entire IP address is matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no $ in your regex so your regex does not asserts position at the end of a line, so it basically doesn't care what comes after 172.20. , see for more info: regex101.com/r/TgjdVz/1

In addition to match all private IPv4 subnets use to following regex.

```
^(10(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{1,2})){3}|((172\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|192\.168)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{1,2})){2})$
```

Comment: How about just including your comment regarding `$` on top of your answer?

Comment: @mikeM: PS C:\Users\Vikas> '192.168.0.121' -match '^192\.168\.'
True

Comment: @Ervin and Bobble - thank you, your comment is helpful in understanding what I was missing. Appreciated.